# Spring ElasticSearch - How to store whole child object inside parent object?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to insert data into elasticsearch. I have Java classes like this,

```
@Data
public class Common {

    @Id
    private String id;
}

@Getter @Setter
public class Student extends Common {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String password;
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}

@Getter @Setter
@Document(indexName = "table")
public class Table extends Common {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Auto, includeInParent = true)
    private Student student;

    private String attends;
}
```

What I need is, I need to store `Student` data (Full Data Object) inside `Table` object in elasticsearch `table` index. I don't want to store Student separately as another index. Instead of that I need to store that data also inside that Table. I tried many ways including `nested and object field types`. But none of them are working. It is not storing whole `student` object inside the `Table` object. It is only inserting `id` of the student.

So how I can achieve that? How to store student object inside table object. Anybody can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the property as `@FieldType.Object`:

```java
@Document(indexName = "table")
public class Table extends Common {

    @Field(type = FieldType.Object)
    private Student student;

    private String attends;
}
```

**Edit:**

I should not answer without trying it out first. The field definition is alright, you need to define getter and setter methods for the properties of the classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but it is not working.

Comment: did you delete the index and have it recreated so that the index mapping is updated?

Comment: Yes I delete it and start the spring application. But still it is saving only the id not the whole object.

Comment: I was wrong with the first answer, see my update, you need getter/setter

Comment: I did a mistake and now it is working fine. Thank you very much for the answer and also for your time.